# Action within commandButton can not be performed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I am new in Primefaces, and I encountered this problem. The action can not be performed unless I move onclick tag.

```
    <p:commandButton value="Détail " action="#{Allcar.gethistorique}" onclick="detail();suppcar.disable();modifscar.disable();comptecar.disable();detcar.disable()"
        id="deta" widgetVar="detcar" disabled="true">
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Do you need the javascript in the onclick to happen before or after the jsf action?

Comment: Why are you disabling the button if you want to be able to click it? If you want to run javascript before the jsf action, then use onstart="your code". If you want to run javascript after the jsf action then use oncomplete=" your code"

Comment: I want to run the action then onclick and after I want that the button becomes not clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the commandButton initially set to disable="true". It won't submit if disabled. If you leave out the disabled="true", it works for me (though I am only using the detcar.disable() in the onclick)

```
<p:commandButton value="Détail " action="#{Allcar.gethistorique}" onclick="detcar.disable()"
            id="deta" widgetVar="detcar">
    </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: #6 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value